# Using XPath, how can I exact text following a tag?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I want to extract **Text2** which without a tag wrapped.

It's next to `div.header-nav`, I'm not sure it's the second text.

```
<body>
  Text1
    <div class="header-nav">
        nav text
    </div>
  Text2
    <div>Something</div>
  Text3
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `Text2` is the second text node directly under `<body>`, this should do it:

```
//text()[parent::body][2]
```

Edit:

If you don't know the position but you know the node it immediately follows, try this:

```
//text()[parent::body][preceding-sibling::div[1][@class="header-nav"]]
```

Comment: It's next to `div.header-nav`, I'm not sure it's the second text.

Comment: @wgf4242 - What do you mean by "next to": immediately following it?

Comment: Yes, immediately following it.